# Create text file to write/add of a couple of images name

Tags: file, io, dm-script

I tried to get a script to create a text file that could write/add the images name, but the function
`FileID = CreateFileForWriting(filename)` does not work, it shows that was used by other process
I did not get this, is this function not right format or something is wrong, thx

```c
    Number Totaln
    totaln=countdocumentwindowsoftype(5)
    String filename, text
    Number fileID
    
    if (!SaveasDialog( "save text file as",getapplicationdirectory(2,0) + "Imagename.txt", filename))exit(0)
    
    fileID = CreateFileForWriting(filename)
    
    number i
    for(i = 0; i <totaln; i++)
    {
    image imgSRC
    imgSRC := GetFrontImage()
    string imgname=getname(imgSRC)
    WriteFile(fileID,"imgname")
    Result("imgname")
    }
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend using the streaming object for file I/O as it is way more flexible. (And has an example in the F1 help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is *nearly* fine, but if you use the low-level API for file I/O you need to ensure that you *close* files you've opened or created.

Your script doesn't. Therefore, it runs fine exactly 1 time but will fail on re-run (when the file is still considered open.)

To fix it, you need to have `closefile(fileID)` at the end.

( BTW, if you script exits or throws after opening a file but before closing it, you have the same problem. )

---

However, I would strongly recommend not using the low-level API but the file streaming object instead. It also provides an automated file-closing mechanism so that you don't run into this issue.

Doing what you do in your script would be written as:

```c
    void writeCurrentImageNamesToText()
    {
        number nDoc = CountImageDocuments()
        string filename
        if (!SaveasDialog( "save text file as",getapplicationdirectory(2,0) + "Imagename.txt", filename))   return
        number fileID = CreateFileForWriting(filename)
        object fStream = NewStreamFromFileReference(fileID,1)   // 1 for auto-close file when out of scope
        for( number i = 0; i <nDoc; i++ ){
            
            string name = GetImageDocument(i).ImageDocumentGetName()
            fStream.StreamWriteAsText( 0, name + "\n" ) // 0 = use system encoding for text
        }
    }
    writeCurrentImageNamesToText()
```

Comment: For this imagedocument(i), we can get size  as getsize(imagedocument(i), xsize, ysize) or getsize (name, xsize, ysize), looks like both are not working, thanks

Comment: ImageDocumentGetSize(GetImageDocument(i)) also does not work

Comment: @together ImageDocuments are files and can contain more than one image (just like you can have more images on a "page" or as annotation of each other.) When you have and `imageDocument` you need to use `ImageDocumentGetImage( index )` to get the specific image.

Comment: @together You may want to post a separate question on "How to get Image properties for ImageDocuments" so that I can post a more complete answer.